# How do I get the Princess?

Tags: super-mario-bros

I'm playing the old Super Mario Bros for the NES for the first time, and I keep getting to the castle with Bowser. However, every time I beat him, I don't get the Princess and instead just get Toad, and then sent out again.

I've tried a bunch of things - killing Bowser by spitting fireballs until he falls off, grabbing the hammer to break the bridge, but nothing seems to work. How do I get the princess?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Defeat Bowser on world 8-4 to rescue the princess.

Answer (score 3):

If you look carefully, you'll notice Toad talking to you (Mario), telling you that the Princess is, in fact, located in another castle.

> [image: A screenshot of a completed x-4 level of Super Mario Bros, showing Toad telling Mario that the Princess is in another castle]
>
> Thank you Mario!
>
> But our Princess is in another castle!

There are 8 worlds in *Super Mario Bros.*, each containing 4 levels, the 4th invariably being a castle. As luck would have it, the Princess is located in the castle of the 8th world, known as level 8-4.
After defeating Bowser in that castle, you will finally find the Princess.

> [image: A screenshot of a completed 8-4 level of Super Mario Bros, with Mario finally finding the Princess]
>
> Thank you Mario!
>
> Your quest is over.
> We present you a new quest.
>
> Push button B to select a world